# How can I use structures from structure blocks in multiple worlds on Xbox One?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

i have seen and read other questions like this one but every time i try to load a structure from a structure block that has a structure saved from one world and loaded in a different world it doesnt load like the file for it does not exist unless im in the original world where i saved it from. help please i made an auto enchanting machine using command blocks and i thought it was originaly just that they cant load in command blocks with commands but i also tested it in the world and it works in that world and i tested it with a normal house and it too loads in that world but not in any other world. i tested both things in a new and old world and realm. any help is great this is really hendering my map making progress.

Answer (score 3):

Sadly structure blocks only save to the world file on bedrock console edition. If you have windows 10 edition you can export files to .mcstructure files which can be placed inside a behavior pack to be loaded and used at will, but this can't be done on just xbox.

Work arounds are:

- Build the structure once in each world you need it. You can use a structure block to save the structure to that world. You only need to do this once then you can build the structure as many times as you want.
- Get windows 10 edition, build the structures and export them as .mcstructure files. Create a behavior pack. Run a Bedrock Dedicated Server on a pc with this behavior pack on the same network as you xbox. Connect to the server as a LAN game on Xbox and then you can use the structures.

Comment: well, i dont currently have a computer that can support java well enough to run alsomst anything. i have an hp chromebook so i guess i could get the linux distro of it but thanks anyway.